# GET all documents from 3 collections in mongoDB API Node Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, foreign-keys

I am having 3 collections in mongoDB. Such as Authors, Events, Agendas. The schema as follows. And I am creating API using Node Express.

```
Authors
-------
_id        PK
name
avatar

Events
------
_id        PK
name
start_time
end_time
user_id    FK

Agendas
-------
_id        PK
name
end_time
event_id   FK
```

This is my URL `http://localhost:3000/events/`

When I go to this URL with GET request, I want to list out that `Event` details(documents), related `Author` details(documents) (which is user_id) and `Agendas` details(documents). In here I am facing the troubles. Here The Agendas has the `event_id` key. I can able to list out Event and User details by the following snippets.

**Events Controller.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const router =express.Router();
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const multer = require('multer');
var assert = require('assert');

// Retrieve and return all programe from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {

   Event.find()
   .populate('user_id')

    .then(programs => {
        res.send(programs);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving programe."
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Please explain ***In here I am facing the troubles. Here The Agendas has the event_id key. I can able to list out Event and User details by the following snippets.***

Comment: Yeah!, This is the` GET` request `URL` `http://localhost:300/programs/id=f5bc589cd52cd2d2`. Now I get `Program` table records and `User` table records only. How can I get the `Agenda` table details also with the `id f5bc589cd52cd2d2`. (Here the ~Agenda` table has multiple records for this program id `f5bc589cd52cd2d2`)

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet : Why so silent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
Event.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Users.collection.name,
    "let": { "user_id": "$user_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$user_id" ] } } },
    ],
    "as": "user_id"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$user_id" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Agenda.collection.name,
    "let": { "evenId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$event_id", "$$evenId" ] } } },
    ],
    "as": "agenda"
  }}
])
```

Comment: @ Anthony Winzlet, Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i cant see your question here, but if you want to find all document from those collections, try using [mongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below query using `aggregate` its help you.

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Authors",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Authors"
        }

    }, 

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Agendas",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "event_id",
            as: "Agendas"
        }

    }, 

    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            start_time:1,
            end_time : 1,
            Authors :1,
            Agendas:1
    }
}])
```

Comment: What is mean by `1` in `$project` ?

Comment: To Return particular fields. 
reference Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/